# Combine 2 query output in one result set

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, join

I have two query output as follow-

### Query-1 Output:

A

B

C

### Query-2 Output:

1

2

3

4

5

Now I am looking forward to join these two outputs that will return me the following output-

### Combine Output:

A     |  1

B     |  2

C     |  3

NULL  |  4

NULL  |  5

Note: There is no relation between the output of Query 1 & 2

Thanks in advance, mkRabbani

Comment: Language(s)? Own effort?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relation is based on the order of the values from table A and B, so we `LEFT JOIN` the results from A (containing the numbers) to the results from B (containing the characters) on the ordered index.

```
DECLARE @a TABLE (col int);
DECLARE @b TABLE (col char(1));
INSERT INTO @a VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO @a VALUES (2);
INSERT INTO @a VALUES (3);
INSERT INTO @a VALUES (4);
INSERT INTO @a VALUES (5);
INSERT INTO @b VALUES ('A');
INSERT INTO @b VALUES ('B');
INSERT INTO @b VALUES ('C');

SELECT B.col, A.col
FROM ( SELECT col, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY col) AS RowNum FROM @a ) AS A
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT col, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY col) AS RowNum FROM @b ) AS B ON A.RowNum = B.RowNum
```

Comment: Using LEFT JOIN will not lead you to the result required. You should use FULL JOIN because you don't know which of the 2 queries will return the highest number of rows.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the desired result by using  Row_Number() and full outer join.

Please check the SQLFiddler, in which I have reproduced the desired result.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/21009/6/0

Answer (score 0):

```
Create Table T1 (col1 nVarchar(10))
Go
Create Table T2 (col1 nvarchar(10))
Go
Insert T1 (col1) Values ('A'), ('B'), ('C')
Insert T2 (col1) Values ('1'), ('2'), ('3'), ('4'), ('5')
Go

;With CTE1 As (
Select col1,
    Row_Number() Over(Order By Col1) Rn
    From T1
), CTE2 As (
    Select col1,
        Row_Number() Over(Order By Col1) Rn
        From T2
    )
    Select CTE1.col1, CTE2.col1 From CTE1 Right Outer Join
            CTE2 On CTE1.Rn = CTE2.Rn
```